# iframe without refresh browser when I change src

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

How do I prevent the browser to not refresh when I change the iframe src?

script load iframe:

```
function load(page, iframe){
var image_load = "<div class='ajax_loading'><img src='"+loading_image_large+"' /></div>";
$.ajax({
    url: site+page,
    dataType: 'json',
    type :'POST', 
    dataType:"html",
    beforeSend: function(){
        $(div).html(image_load);
    },
    success: function(response){
        $(iframe).attr('src', "http://192.168.1.13:8080/server/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&standAlone=true&reportUnit="+ Product.uri +"&j_username=joeuser&j_password=joeuser");
    }       
});
}
```

html :

```
$('#iframex').get(0).contentWindow.location.reload(true);
 //html
<iframe id="iframex" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is make reload because reload=true

Remove line then works fine

```
$('#iframex').get(0).contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: I delete it but it did not work .. after i change iframe src keep reloading the browser..sorry my english so bad

Answer (score 0):

As far i can tell, iframe requires browser page refresh to parse the source. So, when you are changing the src as the ajax returns a data, it is refreshing the page